# java classpath wildcard behaviour

Tags: classpath

I've used the `java -classpath` wildcard expansion feature previously and successfully. I'm currently experiencing a strange problem with it.

The wildcard is supposed to expand to every `jar` in the named folder. Here's a quote from Oracle:

```
Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character *, 
which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files 
in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. For example, the 
class path entry foo/* specifies all JAR files in the directory 
named foo. A classpath entry consisting simply of * expands to a 
list of all the jar files in the current directory.
```

[This is a link to Oracle doc on Java 6 on the subject of classpath.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

The behaviour I am seeing contradicts this.  Here are 3 runs.  The first explicitly names the `jar` and so it works.  The others use a wildcard and fail.  Why?  This matters to me because I rely on wildcards (elsewhere) and so an understanding of this unexpected behaviour is important to me.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "The EV is...\n"
echo $CLASSPATH
printf "The working directory is...\n"
pwd
printf "Directory listing...\n"
ls 
printf "END of directory listing.\n"

printf "Test with named jar.\n"
java -javaagent:../sizeof/sizeof.jar -classpath ./testsizeof.jar info.zqxj.test.Tester

printf "Test with star.\n"
java -javaagent:../sizeof/sizeof.jar -classpath * info.zqxj.test.Tester

printf "Test with dot slash star.\n"
java -javaagent:../sizeof/sizeof.jar -classpath ./* info.zqxj.test.Tester
```

The output:

```
The EV is...

The working directory is...
/home/b/Documents/workspace/testsizeof
Directory listing...
bin  run.sh  src  testsizeof.jar
END of directory listing.
Test with named jar.
40
Test with star.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: run/sh
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: run.sh
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: run.sh.  Program will exit.
Test with dot slash star.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: //run/sh
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ..run.sh
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: ./run.sh.  Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution, double quote the classpath argument.  Example:  `-classpath "*"`   This is necessary  on the command line as well as inside a bash script.

A subsequent addendum:

Furthermore, note that `-classpath "~/folder/*"` fails but `-classpath ~/folder/"*"` is good. Quote the wildcard but do not quote the `~`. It seems that you need the operating system to interpret `~` but you need to quote the `*` wildcard because you want to pass it to `java` for expansion in Java-fashion.

Note also that you should not ask `java` to expand `*.jar` because that will have an unintended result. The Java spec says that the correct wildcard is just the `*` alone.